# Table Designer in Visual Studio 2012 not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm quite new with Visual Studio 2012 and I'm facing such problem:
I can't use table designer, I've followed instructions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172003.aspx but all buttons are disabled

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post a screenshot